# How do I get default theme, font and UI of Visual Studio Code in Visual Studio 17?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, user-interface, visual-studio-2017, color-theme

I understand Visual Studio is an IDE and Visual Studio Code is an "editor" but writing code in Visual Studio Code is damn faster and easier. I just love the UI. I feel there might be an extension in Visual Studio for Visual Studio Code but I could not find one. I would be really grateful if anyone could help me with this. I am fairly new to the industry so I apologize if I missed any guidelines while writing this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get readymade UI theme of visual code in VS 17, but can get a similar dark theme and configure it to look as you desire.

Navigate to Menu Tools > Options > Environment > General > Color Theme -> Select 'Dark' > OK

Then you can play with text fonts and colors at Environments > Fonts and Colors